# Rails 4 Apipie - How to document a parent controller class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, documentation, apipie

I'm using [APIPIE](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails) to document an API that I'm implementing.

I have a class called **BaseController** that implements the methods *create*, *update*, *destroy*, *show*, etc, in a generic way, so any controller that extends *BaseController* will not need to implement those methods.

With Apipie, I'm documenting like this

```
class API::V1::SampleController < API::V1::BaseController
  api! "Create a sample"
  param ....
  def create
    super
  end
end
```

I'm doing this to all controllers that extend BaseController, but I don't think it is a good idea. Is there any way to define the documentation in BaseController itself, so that Apipie generates documentation for every controller in my application that extends it?

Comment: Same situation. Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Nope... Ended up abandoning apipie